# Why can't I loop through numbers downwards in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

The following code (looping from 10 to 1) doesn't run in javascript and I can't figure out why. Any advice?

```
for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x--){
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: Because `x` is not equal to 1; try: `x > 1` the assessment must evaluate to `true`.

Comment: for loops condition must evaluate to true for it to run, [for reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Answer (score 1):

The test in a loop says when to keep looping, not when to stop. When your loop starts, `x = 10`, so `x == 1` is false, and the loop stops immediately.

It should be:

```
for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x--)
```

Answer (score 0):

you are setting x = 10, then looping while x == 1, which it isn't so you never loop. You should use "x > 0".  The test in the loop is "loop as long as this condition is true".

Answer (score 0):

That's not working because the syntax is not correct. It should be:

```
for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x--){
    console.log(x);
}
```

The x==1 expression is the stopping condition of the loop and, when it's false, loop stops.

Answer (score 0):

you are using for loop . for for loop syntax is :
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    code block to be executed
}

Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts.

Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block).

Statement 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has been executed.

so according to yours code :
     for (var x = 10; x == 1; x--){
        console.log(x);
    }

it will first assign x to 10 then it will check condition which is x==1 it will return false and loop will stop. so current version will be:
     for (var x = 10; x >= 1; x--){
        console.log(x);
    }